# div and display property for screen readers

Tags: html, css, screen-readers

If I have a `div`:

```
<div style="display:block">hello</div>
```

… and another `div`:

```
<div style="display:inline">hello</div>
```

Will a screen reader "read" them differently?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9 Voiceover: No.
Android 5 Talkback: No.
NVDA 2016.1: Not as far as I used it for testing.

In both cases the screenreader may do a little "breath" break so the listener knows that the content is in a new element.

Answer (score -3):

**Inline elements:**

- take care of the left and right margins.
- do not take care of top and bottom.
- do not contain width and height.
- allow other elements to align them to their sideways.
- line break not required after every element.

**Block elements:**

- Take care of everything mentioned in above(margins, top, bottom).
- have width and height.
- no sideways alignment.
- makes a line break after every element.

hope that answers your query. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what does your answer have to do with screen-readers (such as JAWS)?

Comment: [This](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201111/screen_readers_and_css/) might help you to understand.
apologies that initially I misunderstood your question.